# How can I modify time on x-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot with r and I would like to change the time on the x-axis. There should be labels for every hour. I used:  `scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 hour", labels=date_format("%H:%M"))`, but unfortunately, it is not working. Does someone has an idea? Thanks for helping.

This is my code:

```
input2 <- "C:\\Users\\time_distance.csv"
time_distance <- read.csv(input2, sep=";")

library(scales)
time <- strptime(time_distance$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

plot2 <-ggplot(time_distance, aes(x = time, y = distance, group = 1)) +     
  geom_point(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, color = "red", se = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "Distance [m]", x = "time [hour]")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1600), breaks = seq(100, 1500, 100))

print(plot2)
```

This is my data:

```
dput(time_distance)

structure(list(time = c("12:51:57", "12:55:16", "12:56:29", "13:25:05", 
"13:36:54", "13:55:37", "14:11:20", "14:13:17", "15:14:26", "15:18:48", 
"15:21:01", "15:22:29", "15:25:13", "15:28:16", "15:28:26", "15:39:58", 
"15:46:49", "15:50:45", "15:59:51", "16:02:38", "16:24:05", "16:35:17", 
"11:15:24", "13:32:40", "14:42:39", "15:24:08", "15:32:28", "16:43:48", 
"16:48:42", "17:10:28", "17:27:55", "11:23:25", "12:19:21", "12:27:19", 
"12:28:39", "12:47:18", "13:17:01", "14:06:26", "14:15:35", "14:18:06", 
"14:26:26", "14:50:32", "15:25:26", "15:33:50", "15:56:02", "15:58:45", 
"16:11:02", "16:35:42", "17:16:24", "17:28:30", "08:58:43", "09:55:52", 
"10:14:17", "10:24:17", "10:36:42", "10:55:35", "14:18:29", "14:36:59", 
"15:22:46", "15:51:35", "15:58:29", "16:36:36", "16:47:48", "13:33:52", 
"14:31:38", "14:49:03", "16:13:31", "11:11:20", "11:46:00", "11:50:43", 
"12:13:11", "13:07:31", "13:27:46", "14:37:37", "15:27:51", "10:07:52", 
"10:18:18", "11:56:53", "12:18:37", "12:45:55", "13:14:20", "13:23:21", 
"13:30:15", "13:31:34", "13:33:12", "13:48:06", "13:53:52", "14:30:18", 
"14:44:24", "14:51:14", "15:03:19", "15:33:32", "15:49:00", "15:55:53", 
"16:07:24", "16:11:43", "16:21:43", "16:35:50", "16:39:37", "16:48:41", 
"10:02:45", "12:14:40", "13:10:27", "14:36:28", "14:51:12", "15:38:50", 
"15:58:29", "10:53:33", "11:11:27", "11:32:26", "11:38:36", "12:56:03", 
"13:45:09", "14:39:48", "14:51:57", "14:53:25", "15:08:02", "16:01:32", 
"16:22:14", "16:46:01", "08:57:18", "09:07:51", "09:25:10", "09:34:32", 
"10:15:35", "10:33:54", "11:07:55", "11:26:00", "11:40:21", "11:50:45", 
"11:57:16", "12:55:00", "13:21:18", "14:47:07", "14:50:21", "14:56:56", 
"15:06:39", "15:21:53", "15:36:26", "15:48:37", "15:54:50", "16:01:28", 
"16:12:21", "16:21:53", "16:26:20", "16:30:52", "09:49:00", "10:13:53", 
"10:27:21", "10:46:43", "12:24:04", "12:30:04", "12:54:33", "13:33:14", 
"13:52:55", "14:12:14", "14:37:37", "14:42:58", "14:44:37", "14:51:39", 
"15:08:57", "15:38:08", "15:49:06", "16:05:53", "17:01:34", "08:31:56", 
"09:44:00", "10:19:35", "10:47:49", "11:18:16", "11:35:49", "12:32:43", 
"12:43:45", "13:11:05", "13:24:34", "13:32:46", "13:42:01", "14:20:17", 
"14:31:11", "14:36:30", "16:06:58", "08:30:07", "09:02:22", "10:03:07", 
"10:29:09", "10:52:23", "11:47:59", "12:58:26", "13:47:26", "13:53:05", 
"14:08:33", "14:16:46", "14:28:50", "15:16:42", "16:07:43", "08:27:08", 
"08:52:03", "09:04:13", "09:14:04", "09:22:39", "09:32:25", "09:39:04", 
"10:18:02", "13:06:58", "13:21:03", "13:37:28", "13:41:09", "14:17:06", 
"14:36:17", "14:51:45"), distance = c(89.6472646, 162.833946, 
204.1718123, 69.32061609, 145.5725233, 157.8104904, 142.7204165, 
139.4100682, 156.290279, 281.1730457, 211.3723597, 146.9900352, 
155.5278723, 121.630972, 115.0260845, 103.4678487, 535.2962882, 
172.2392646, 187.1019506, 192.2072681, 163.1432699, 328.1146666, 
161.378541, 276.9657775, 288.6843714, 232.236379, 286.5742551, 
171.9799195, 131.3821584, 645.23548, 328.8999153, 83.1376454, 
206.8425108, 160.1471859, 163.4999165, 71.84934976, 122.7265289, 
156.6223912, 245.7737619, 76.4010552, 191.7314754, 241.2484589, 
314.4240603, 168.1778327, 249.4432742, 171.5837494, 445.289732, 
150.781544, 231.0174121, 233.6595053, 212.0908014, 274.9652469, 
230.2231595, 463.3457859, 185.4275877, 413.7982665, 225.4934765, 
171.8698762, 287.8326822, 457.6477022, 216.539991, 203.7116093, 
261.3755307, 176.3162834, 113.2523456, 186.0197098, 110.2207489, 
164.0611501, 111.7164405, 157.4453558, 158.5689564, 155.240531, 
117.3045189, 117.6454036, 224.4921484, 326.2455013, 205.1963079, 
166.1579876, 245.2281083, 168.9163027, 280.1466904, 331.9011914, 
268.5518097, 296.9010562, 476.5082804, 391.8845907, 255.7662667, 
483.9525726, 283.381313, 592.5282434, 158.4318925, 722.0857244, 
1524.855308, 261.3729014, 495.6679407, 585.3051787, 485.0507777, 
472.889667, 394.5888053, 328.1134478, 209.4992859, 161.8100828, 
179.8945385, 438.95502, 538.0923178, 142.1052511, 150.0340155, 
170.1366692, 123.6032668, 171.7141119, 98.76667809, 235.874407, 
241.7648426, 224.3868202, 167.1152772, 67.44743255, 87.79127323, 
150.6129032, 476.6532019, 186.2234702, 139.4749401, 102.0916653, 
69.80207399, 77.6190789, 179.4630148, 109.0492763, 165.9927234, 
228.9755043, 247.591346, 262.0171879, 155.9824185, 207.1022985, 
121.5681699, 178.136665, 126.386831, 74.78485864, 71.12781299, 
78.21953935, 317.1932926, 219.2749766, 247.6333865, 98.85128473, 
235.0537481, 90.20871946, 124.2324844, 125.3904596, 248.5174138, 
148.2374205, 299.5611988, 77.88228217, 194.0273272, 117.208969, 
347.7014402, 306.3749268, 313.0498324, 313.7161044, 479.518518, 
314.9932, 271.3977789, 274.4941856, 391.3815061, 418.8094285, 
243.0563698, 599.4055807, 169.8079415, 70.72250265, 181.7665702, 
172.3945082, 95.23804572, 147.9418742, 101.8629435, 127.5025047, 
236.7513256, 113.5718566, 133.5204809, 215.6790291, 72.40720193, 
80.22093147, 188.9783062, 75.71888165, 100.6934031, 293.32912, 
269.7824729, 772.4577258, 468.3636793, 221.4304232, 282.6939389, 
250.2391573, 111.5475549, 181.1174836, 221.0176637, 206.4821957, 
127.4349516, 112.25765, 198.9440625, 144.8789547, 86.23383985, 
48.90437015, 107.9818848, 186.2547336, 156.2620094, 112.5252141, 
349.3143126, 342.4842646, 69.19741708, 206.0086208, 211.6554678, 
119.8004909, 136.4785611, 111.8184516)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -210L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column time should be `POSIXct` to be able to use `scale_x_datetime`, convert it to the right type and it will work.

This should work:

```
library(scales)
time_distance$time <- as.POSIXct(time_distance$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

ggplot(time_distance, aes(x=time, y=distance, group=1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm , color="red", se=FALSE) +theme(legend.position="none") + 
  theme_bw()+
  labs(y = "Distance [m]", x = "time [hour]")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1600), breaks=seq(100, 1500, 100)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 hour", labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working to use just as.POSIXct. It says: Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument

Comment: You need to use the lubridate package to get your dates in the correct format! try that first and see if it corrects the error!

Comment: Did you change anything in the data? or is it the same data you posted in the question? because it worked fine with me, I added the plot I got to the answer

Comment: Can you try ``date_breaks`` instead of  ``breaks`` in the ``scale_x_datetime``?

Comment: Now, it is working. Thank you so much. I have to use date_breaks instead of breaks.